# Select based on cumulative sum MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of a mind-bender (for me) SQL query. I have a database with incoming/outgoing records, then wrote a query with the cumulative sum, grouped by each product name / SKU - the query is as follows:

```
select e.*
     , (SELECT sum(e2.qty) FROM inventory_log e2 WHERE e2.product_id = e.product_id ) as running_tot 
  FROM inventory_log e 
 GROUP 
    BY product_name
```

This seems to work quite well (unless any of you see something incorrect). My next step is to generate inventory alerts (ie if any cumulative sum <=50).

Would I need to do another sub-query in order to do this? Any jumping off point is helpful!

Comment: What is MySQL version?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. `SELECT *`  and `GROUP BY` do not go along well together, which makes the purpose of your current query rather unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating a simple aggregation by using a correlated subquery.
Your query can be written as simple as this:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, SUM(qty) AS running_tot 
FROM inventory_log 
GROUP BY product_id, product_name
```

If you want only the products with running_tot < 50 you can add a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING running_tot < 50
```